# How to call android GCM from meteor

Tags: android, meteor, google-cloud-messaging

I want to use Android GCM in my android framework.

I've seen https://github.com/h2soft/node-gcm
But it's an npm, I don't know if it can be used in meteor.

Thank you for any hints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've made a package that could use this. I haven't got the chance to put it on atmosphere yet. (Here it is on dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1mpwygl30deo1es/node-gcm.zip)

You can use `gcm` as on https://github.com/ToothlessGear/node-gcm anywhere on your server side javascript code.

e.g (simplified version that can work)

```
var message = new gcm.Message();

var message = new gcm.Message({
    collapseKey: 'demo',
    delayWhileIdle: true,
    timeToLive: 3,
    data: {
        key1: 'message1',
    }
});

var sender = new gcm.Sender('insert Google Server API Key here');
var registrationIds = [];

registrationIds.push('regId2'); 

sender.send(message, registrationIds, 4, function (err, result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

To make a call from the client you need to interface it with a `Meteor.call`